# What is tcsh equivalent of bash $'\t'

Tags: tcsh

I'm trying to use `column -t -s $'\t'` in tcsh (which works in bash) but I can't find a way to make it work

```
echo "selected version\tnew version\nbbb\tccc\n" | column -t -s $'\t'
Illegal variable name
```

So what's the equivalent in tcsh?

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcsh doesn't have a mechanism for including non-printing characters in string literals, other than including them directly.

In bash, you can do this (changing `echo` to `printf` because its behavior is more consistent):

```
$ printf "selected version\tnew version\nbbb\tccc\n" | column -t -s $'\t'
selected version  new version
bbb               ccc
```

In tcsh, you can replace the `$'\t'` with a literal tab character, entered by typing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> -- but when you read the code it's indistinguishable from a sequence of spaces.

Here's one solution, using the `printf` command to convert `\t` to a tab character:

```
% printf "selected version\tnew version\nbbb\tccc\n" | column -t -s "`printf '\t'`"
selected version  new version
bbb               ccc
```

You can also store the tab character in a variable; you can use either double quotes or the `:t` suffix to retain the literal value when you use it:

```
% set tab = "`printf '\t'`"
% printf "selected version\tnew version\nbbb\tccc\n" | column -t -s "$tab"
selected version  new version
bbb               ccc
% printf "selected version\tnew version\nbbb\tccc\n" | column -t -s $tab:q
selected version  new version
bbb               ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

in general, you just ust "\t" for a tab.  However, column seems to intepret this literally as a backslash and a letter t.  To get around this, you can explicitly enter a tab character by pressing cntl-v and then tab (surrounded by quotes).

Note however, in the case of your specific example, you do not need the -s argument at all, since column separates by whitespace by default.

Comment: No, in general `"\t"` is a string consisting of a backslash followed by a letter `t`. *Some* commands will convert that sequence to a tab character. `column` does use whitespace by default, but the man page *doesn't* say it uses tab characters.